# Execute an ethereum transaction every X amount of blocks within a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, randomness, block-interval, scheduling

I would like to build a smart contract where users deposit crypto into a lottery like system. Every 10 blocks that have passed on the underlying chain I want to generate a random number and send out a transaction to the winners. Is there aany solidity mechanism or library I can use in order to monitor the propagated blocks in the chain and execute a function on every 10th block?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into chainlink automation (formerly known as 'chainlink keepers' contracts to help you achieve this.

Look [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-automation/introduction/).

Hope this will help you!